# Getting wrong result with Number.isInteger() method, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I've been trying the Number.isInteger() method on chrome console.
and after doing a for loop and checking the result with the `console.log(arr);` I'm getting an array with only one value of 1. like this `[1];`

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,'some','string'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Number.isInteger(arr[i])) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr[i], 1));
    }
}
```

Any one have an idea, if I'm doing it wrong or something. thanks for help.

Comment: You want to keep only integers??

Comment: method does not have full browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What is expected result of `.splice()` call `arr`?

Comment: No, ibrahim mahrir. I want the opposite.

Comment: guest271314, Well, the result should be the array with the strings only without any number

Comment: charlietfl,  It could be a support problem

Comment: That isn't the main issue...it is the array length changes you make splicing in the for loop. Note polyfill in docs to add browser support

Comment: charlietfl , good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a major problem, you are continually removing items from the array while looping through it. You have to go back one step (`i--`) every time an item is removed.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,'some','string'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(arr[i])) { // isNaN return true if it's not a valid number, so we have to inverse the test
        arr.splice(i, 1); // if it's a valid number remove the element at the index i (no need to search for the index using indexOf, we already have it its i)
        i--;              // if we remove an element, we have to go back one step (or we will leave one item behind every time we remove another)
    }
}


console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use typeof instead:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,'some','string'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] == 'number') {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(arr[i], 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunate Gianni, I got same result.

Comment: problem is from splicing in loop

Answer (score 0):

The `.splice()' method makes changes to the array itself.

So for each iteration of the array, you are changing it fundamentally.

If you want the array to include only integers:

```
    var arr = [1,2,3,'some','string'];

    var newArray = [];

    arr.forEach(function(element) {
        if (Number.isInteger(element)){
            newArray.push(element);
        }
    });

    console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Good one. and it works, just adding !  before Number in the if statement to have only the strings

Comment: Good reading material on Number object in ES6: https://hackernoon.com/what-you-should-know-about-numbers-in-es6-javascript-7370be6b3469#.4sr1har36